# What does "key_load_public: no such file or directory" mean?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I've been troubleshooting a `PubkeyAuthentication`-only issue. When I use verbose mode, I see a lot of *"key_load_public: no such file or directory"*.

Obviously, the keys exits on the filesystem, so that message does not appear to have a customary meaning:

```
$ ls -al ~/.ssh/id_*
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   751 Feb  4  2013 id_dsa
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   608 Feb 18  2015 id_dsa.pub
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   314 Feb  4  2013 id_ecdsa
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   180 Feb 18  2015 id_ecdsa.pub
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   464 Aug 23 18:15 id_ed25519
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   103 Aug 23 18:15 id_ed25519.pub
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff  2546 Feb  4  2013 id_rsa
-rw-------  1 jwalton  staff   572 Feb 18  2015 id_rsa.pub
```

What, exactly, does *"key_load_public: no such file or directory"* mean?

---

My `.ssh/config` file has:

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/config
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Adding the `*.pub` extension has no effect. I tried both with and without `*.pub` because the man page is ambiguous with respect to which key needs to be specified - public or private. (A pubic key is all that's needed for an identity; a private key is needed to prove ownership of the key in a challenge/response):

```
IdentityFile
    Specifies a file from which the user's DSA, ECDSA or DSA authen-
    tication identity is read...
```

---

```
$ ssh -v -p 1522 jwalton@192.168.1.11
OpenSSH_7.1p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2d 9 Jul 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jwalton/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /usr/local/etc/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.11 [192.168.1.11] port 1522.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub type 4
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_ecdsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_dsa.pub type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_dsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_rsa.pub type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/jwalton/.ssh/id_rsa.pub-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
...
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It means literally what it says: there is no such file or directory that ssh wanted to access.

However, it talks about the file mentioned **below**, not above. You have just the regular public keys, but you do not have the SSH *certificates* for them (presumably because you just don't need them). OpenSSH however will always try to load the associated `.pub-cert` file for each identity key.

---

The ssh-keygen(1) manual talks about creating an OpenSSH cert authority and signing certificates, should you be interested. (Note: this doesn't use X.509, only OpenSSH's own cert format.)

Usually the certificates are only useful if you have a massive amount of users (and/or servers) but don't want to use Kerberos.

Comment: Thanks Grawity. For `IdentityFile`, what should I specify? The public key or the private key?

Comment: It should be the private key file (which actually contains the whole keypair – the extra `.pub` file is only for [sort of] convenience).

Comment: Ooph, now that's confusing. Someone should really file a bug report :-(

Comment: If by "file a bug report" you mean "submit the fix", then feel free to do so: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/README#L38 :). Here's a place to start looking: https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/key.c#L342 and https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh.c#L2091 .

Comment: Sometimes "bug report" literally means "bug report". Not every openssh user is a C programmer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I tried to clone a gitlab project, and the solution should work for any git service. The error was

```
#15 0.589 debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1, 
#15 0.589 debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

It disappeared after using

```
echo "Host *\n  User git\n  HostName gitlab.com\n  AddKeysToAgent yes\n  IdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa" >> /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

This is also what is being asked for in your message block:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
...
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

The solution proves that ssh needs to check the server to be a known host. If you have not assigned the needed known host, the gitlab server is not being trusted, which is meant by `the key_load_public cannot be found`. Yes, the error message is confusing.

You can also manually fill that ssh_config without the `echo` command, of course.

I have just seen that this was also the solution on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/a/822962/607547).