# Can't use SSH anymore on Gitlab runner, "Host key verification failed."

Tags: ssh, gitlab

The server in question is a runner and builds projects with a system user `gitlab-runner`. That user is used to SSH into other servers to deploy code, etc..

Always worked fine until we added a new server as destination. The command `SSH` now always fails with the error **'Host key verification failed.'**. The error is also thrown when I try other servers that worked before. The `known_hosts` file is cleared but SSH doesn't ask to add the server to `known_hosts` anymore, it returns the error message directly.

I checked the permissions of the `~/.ssh` folder and files. These are correct (`.ssh: 700`, `known_hosts: 600`, `id_rsa: 600`, `id_rsa.pub: 644`). Als rebooted the server but no success.

It feels like SSH is not working correctly. Here is a debug output of connecting to a server through `SSH`.

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to megatron.domain.com [10.139.20.204] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to megatron.achillescm.nl:22 as 'root'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:/zgPQuuy6sG8UuLG9EHFSFAuY1QYNvQzKSyNYq//DJ0
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such device or address
Host key verification failed.
```

Anybody an idea?

Comment: `ssh` is indeed trying to ask you about accepting (and adding) the host key, but for some reason `/dev/tty` cannot be opened. I've never seen that, and it suggests something is quite messed up on your system, but with the info given I have no clue what. (The function name `read_passphrase` is somewhat misleading here; it is also called from `confirm` in `ssh_connect.c`) If you manually rebuild known_hosts e.g. with `ssh-keyscan` it should avoid this particular problem, although what else may go wrong I cannot say.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thx for the comment. The system is a very simple setup; ubuntu + gitlab runner, nothing more.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. The problem was that the `known_hosts` file had the wrong permissions.

It was set to `600` and it should be `644`.

Comment: It gives me error: Permissions 0644 for 'SSH_PRIVATE_KEY' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.

Answer (score 0):

```
debug1: identity file /home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
```

Above lines suggest that `.ssh/id_rsa` exists (`type 1`), but its public key (`.ssh/id_rsa.pub`) for the user doesn't or got some problems (`type -1`).

So make sure the file `~/.ssh/id_rsa` exists, has `600` permission, is owned by the user. And the `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` matches/belongs to the same identity (as per this [post](https://serverfault.com/q/558997/130437)).

Here is a simple test to run as a *sudo* access user (e.g. `root`):

```
sudo -u gitlab-runner sh -c 'cd; wc -l .ssh/id_rsa; stat .ssh/id_rsa; head -n1 .ssh/id_rsa'
```

See also: [What does "key_load_public: no such file or directory" mean?](https://superuser.com/q/962888/87805)

Comment: Exactly the opposite; `type 1` means `id_rsa` could be read and does contain an RSA key. (Other algorithms are other positive numbers; _negative_ one is an error.) corrected: It isn't finding the _subsequent_ file `id_rsa-cert`.

Comment: The command you specified returns `bash: line 0: cd: /root: Permission denied
wc: .ssh/id_rsa: Permission denied
stat: cannot stat '.ssh/id_rsa': Permission denied`. When I execute the command after `su gitlab-runner -` then it returns: `File: '.ssh/id_rsa'
  Size: 3243       Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: fd01h/64769d Inode: 283738      Links: 1
Access: (0600/-rw-------)  Uid: (  999/gitlab-runner)   Gid: (  998/gitlab-runner)
Acces..`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, the same problem arises if /dev/tty permissions are too restrictive. Then you can only ssh to a server properly as user root, nobody else can.
The fix is to chmod 777 /dev/tty so the others can do it.

Comment: 666 is probably just as good (or maybe better). I don't know of any reason to give execute permission to a device.

Answer (score 0):

While debugging a similar thing, the awesome problem was a missing line-break (`\n`) at the private key file end.

You may check for the inconsistency using

```
cat ~/.ssh/identity_file
```

The public key file - i.e. `~/.ssh/identity_file.pub` - isn't need to succesfully authenticate against the target host, assuming it has being authorized within target host's `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.